# How can i render the page after one query ( find or save ) is performed on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB . I have written  code in which I am searching the data from the database ,
it works fine for the first search and gives the result but after the result is achieved then if I again perform some query then it do not works  that is it keeps on rendering the page in which query is being made .
Below is the code snippet .

```
app.get('/problems/:a?',(req,res)=>{
var getpath = req.params.a;
    problemModel.find({path:getpath},function(err,data){
    if(err) throw err;
    res.render(''+getpath,{record:data[0]});
    conn.close();
    });
```

});

Please help me out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your solution. Using async/await operators, instead of callbacks, the code is cleaner.

```js
app.get('/problems/:path', async (req, res) => {
   const { path } = req.params; // Equal to "const path = req.params.path"

   try {
      const data = await problemModel.find({ path: path });

      res.render(path, { record: data[0] });
   } catch (e) {
      res.render('path-to-error-page');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @federico-dondi  , it helped me .

Comment: Happy to be helpful.